# The Super User blog is going away

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

We've been trying to kickstart the [SU blog](http://blog.superuser.com/) again, and well, it's mostly been tumbleweeds. We've had little to no activity, despite a few well meaning plans to.

That said, networkwide, blogs are going away - there's no formal announcement as yet, though [the writing's on the wall](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285478/blogoverflow-text-overflow#comment931836_285478). It's not due to lack of updates - it's simply happening network wide.

From what I've been told (and I'll update this if any corrections are needed) we have a few options. Some of the other communities are migrating to other platforms. If we are, SE would provide us with a data dump, and assist as needed. Naturally though, we'd still need to provide content to a successor blog.

They've also said they'll be archiving the existing content with static pages.

While I'd like to let everyone who has ever been involved with the blog know, that's a bit tricky.

At this point, it's probably good to know what our potential options, and ideas of how we're going forward are.

Archiving the site means existing content's there. As things are, that's pretty close to 'status quo'.

If we *are* moving out - where to? What platforms would work, and who would run it? We'd also need to work out how to get regular content.

Probably missed a few things - I'll update, but feel free to discuss.

Comment: If we actually want to do this, content could include weekly highlights from SU - but we'd need more than just that.

Comment: I didn't even know that "normal" users like me could write for the blog...

Comment: Yup, and essentially work out how to get people to know they can write, and actually write, and well, host and run the blog and so on. I'm personally skeptical of this

Comment: It sounds like the blogs, in general, aren't filling a need for very many people.  They do compete with endless external content.  There should probably be some data gathering on what our audience would find worthwhile and compelling.

Comment: I think the irony is @JourneymanGeek should have done this as a blog post...

Comment: For anyone else who was confused by the "writing's on the wall" link, you're supposed to look at the *comments* there, not at the question.

Comment: This was really fun back in the day, I'm sad to see it go, but times change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well it's been a good run, and I wish we could keep it up, but with the blog no longer receiving official SE support I think it's time to finally set it to rest.

Migrating to a new platform not officially supported requires new challenges that I don't think are worth going through for something that is already dead for now; namely user authentication.

That doesn't mean that we can't resurrect the blog if there's plenty of interest out there but after personally trying several times, there just doesn't appear to be enough of that interest *right now* to keep it around.